# multiple nested SELECT query's and sum two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql table that Im trying to run a single/*nested* query on.

```
SELECT 
`subscriber_id`, 
(SELECT...?) AS total_campaigns, 
(SELECT...?) AS total_opens,
(total_opens / total_campaigns) as percentage
FROM
`campaigns_table`
```

The `type` column with a value = 2 shows that the campaign was opened.

Im looking to return a result set with all `subscriber_id`'s that has the total campaigns and total opens

---

## Query Result Data

```
+---------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
| subscriber_id | total_campaigns | total_opens | percentage |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
|             1 |               2 |           1 |        0.5 |
|             2 |               2 |           2 |        1.0 |
|             3 |               2 |           0 |        0.0 |
|             4 |               1 |           0 |        0.0 |
|             5 |               1 |           1 |        1.0 |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
```

subscriber_id 1 would be `total_campaigns` = 2 ( campaign_id's 37428,37239 ) and `total_opens` = 1 ( only campaign_id 27428 has a type 2 record )

---

## Example Table Data

`+---------------+-------------+------------+-------+------+---------+
| subscriber_id | campaign_id | timestamp  | count | type | link_id |
+---------------+-------------+------------+-------+------+---------+
|             1 |       37428 | 1434513738 |     1 |    1 |       0 |
|             1 |       37428 | 1434513758 |     1 |    1 |       0 |
|             1 |       37428 | 1434513338 |     2 |    2 |       0 |
|             1 |       37429 | 1434511738 |     1 |    1 |       0 |
|             1 |       37429 | 1434311738 |     1 |    1 |       1 |
|             2 |       37428 | 1534513738 |     1 |    1 |       0 |
|             2 |       37428 | 1534513758 |     1 |    1 |       0 |
|             2 |       37428 | 1534513338 |     2 |    2 |       0 |
|             2 |       37429 | 1534511738 |     1 |    1 |       1 |
|             2 |       37429 | 1534311738 |     1 |    2 |       0 |
|             3 |       37428 | 1534513738 |     1 |    1 |       0 |
|             3 |       37429 | 1534511738 |     1 |    1 |       1 |
|             4 |       57428 | 1534513738 |     1 |    1 |       0 |
|             4 |       57428 | 1534513758 |     1 |    1 |       0 |
|             5 |       57428 | 1534513338 |     3 |    2 |       0 |
+---------------+-------------+------------+-------+------+---------+`

---

Using the answer from @spencer7593 below. How can I then use the results to update another table?

trying to do something like this (it doesn't work how I have it)

```
    UPDATE `subscribers` a
    LEFT JOIN `campaigns_table` b ON a.`ID` = b.`subscriber_id`
    SET a.`STATUS` = 2
    FROM(
        SELECT t.subscriber_id
             , COUNT(DISTINCT t.campaign_id)                   AS total_campaigns
             , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t.type=2,t.campaign_id,NULL)) AS open_campaigns
             , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t.type=2,t.campaign_id,NULL))
             / COUNT(DISTINCT t.campaign_id)                   AS percentage
        FROM `campaigns_table` t
        GROUP BY t.subscriber_id  
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.campaign_id) > 5 AND COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t.type=2,t.campaign_id,NULL)) = 0
        ORDER BY t.subscriber_id
    ) i
```

Comment: What are the queries for total_campaigns and total_opens?  You can't use total_campaigns and total_opens for the percentage as you've written it because those columns are not in table campaigns_table

Comment: Correct. The total_campaigns and total_opens are not valid columns. I was just using that as an example of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like a problem that can be addressed with conditional aggregation, with a single pass through the table, with no need for any nested queries.

```
SELECT t.subscriber_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT t.campaign_id)                   AS total_campaigns
     , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t.type=2,t.campaign_id,NULL)) AS open_campaigns
     , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t.type=2,t.campaign_id,NULL))
     / COUNT(DISTINCT t.campaign_id)                   AS percentage
  FROM `campaigns_table` t
 GROUP BY t.subscriber_id  
 ORDER BY t.subscriber_id
```

---

It is possible to generate an equivalent result with nested queries, but in general, a single pass through the table (with a single SELECT) will have a more efficient access plan.

If there's a requirement to use nested queries (I don't understand why there would be), in general, I'd prefer to use inline views over correlated queries in the SELECT list.

```
SELECT q.subscriber_id
     , SUM(1)                       AS total_campaigns
     , SUM(q.open_campaign)         AS open_campaigns
     , SUM(q.open_campaign)/SUM(1)  AS percentage
  FROM ( SELECT t.subscriber_id
              , t.campaign
              , MAX(t.type=2) AS `open_campaign`
           FROM `campaigns_table` t
          WHERE t.campaign IS NOT NULL
          GROUP
             BY t.subscriber_id
              , t.campaign
       ) q
 ORDER BY q.subscriber
```

If we want to use nested queries in the SELECT list, those would be correlated subqueries...

```
SELECT s.subscriber
     , (      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.campaign) 
                FROM `campaigns_table` t
               WHERE t.subscriber = s.subscriber
       ) AS total_campaigns

     , (      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.campaign) 
                FROM `campaigns_table` o
               WHERE o.subscriber = s.subscriber
                 AND o.type=2
       ) AS open_campaigns

     , (      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT po.campaign)
                FROM `campaigns_table` po
               WHERE po.subscriber = s.subscriber
                 AND po.type=2
       )
     / (      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pt.campaign) 
                FROM `campaigns_table` pt
                WHERE pt.subscriber = s.subscriber
       ) AS percentage

  FROM ( SELECT r.subscriber
           FROM `campaigns_table` r
         GROUP BY r.subscriber
       ) s
 ORDER BY s.subscriber
```

Comment: How can I use the results to update another table? I need to take each `subscriber_id` found, HAVING a `open_campaigns` = 0 , and set the `status` in another table (`subscribers`).